# Jenkins Pipeline failing but no errors?

Tags: jenkins, github, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have the folowing Pipeline Script that seems to be failing at some point. The CredentialId is correct, the github URL is correct, the path to dotnet is correct, and I'm like 99% sure the syntax is correct because the output (below) is reading my script correctly. So, I'm just wondering if I'm doing something incorrect.

I've never used Jenkins or any CI/CD tools before so this is all new to me.

My hopeful goal is to be able to get Jenkins to build and run a .NET app every-time something is merged with master, but I'm just trying to get this to build successfully every hour, or just to get it to build successfully when I click Build Now in Jenkins itself.

(Also, if there is an easy way to modify my script to run with every master merge, instead of every hour, that would be super helpful!)

```
pipeline{
    agent any
    
    environment {
        dotnet ='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\dotnet\\'
        }
        
    triggers {
        pollSCM 'H * * * *'
    }
 
     stages{
         stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                git credentialsId: '0b02e39b-17f0-4628-ba3d-24146ec7a469', url: 'https://github.com/bellingboe/OktaKenkinsCI.git', branch: 'master'
             }
          }
          
        stage('Restore packages'){
           steps{
              bat "dotnet restore C:\\Users\\Brenden\\Documents\\GitHub\\OktaKenkinsCI\\OktaKenkinsCI.csproj"
             }
          }
          
        stage('Clean'){
            steps{
                bat "dotnet clean C:\\Users\\Brenden\\Documents\\GitHub\\OktaKenkinsCI\\OktaKenkinsCI.csproj"
             }
           }
           
        stage('Build'){
           steps{
              bat "dotnet build C:\\Users\\Brenden\\Documents\\GitHub\\OktaKenkinsCI\\OktaKenkinsCI.csproj --configuration Releas'"
            }
         }
         
     }
  
 }
```

which gives me the following output:

```
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\JenkinsPipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Checkout)
[Pipeline] git
The recommended git tool is: NONE
using credential 0b02e39b-17f0-4628-ba3d-24146ec7a469
 > git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/bellingboe/OktaKenkinsCI.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/bellingboe/OktaKenkinsCI.git
 > git.exe --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.29.2.windows.3'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git.exe fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/bellingboe/OktaKenkinsCI.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
 > git.exe rev-parse "origin/master^{commit}" # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Restore packages)
Stage "Restore packages" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Clean)
Stage "Clean" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
Stage "Build" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Is there something in my script that's wrong? I can't really tell what would be failing as I'm not seeing any errors at all.

Comment: I see an error at the bottom? `ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.`

Comment: Oh. Huh. I'm not even sure what it means, or how to fix it, being that the repo is very much there--Jenkins typo (Kenkins) and all.

Comment: Regarding the triggers, I believe it can be configured within Jenkins that it should run on commits. Cannot remember the details though and do not use Jenkins myself these days. Maybe it was when configuring a multibranch project, something like that :)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. My master branch was named "main" in github.

and I had a typo!

Comment: I am glad you figured this out, but unfortunately answers based on typos are in a category for closure on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Exactly my case. Thank you Brenden Ellingboe